# WPF window close is not working in one click

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I am alerting the user about the process complete like :

```
var result = MessageBox.Show("Completed!!", "Upload Status", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{
    result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Quit the application ?", "Quit Application", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);

    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        OpenWebSite();

        // I want to close the message box and complete application.

    }
}
```

If I write this.Close..It is giving exception, So I wrote it like this :

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { this.Close(); }));
```

Still the page is only closing after two click on [Yes] button, which is making the the `OpenWebSite();` to be called two times. ...

Any idea on what is causing this?

Comment: Please tell us what exception is being thrown and what the body of your `OpenWebSite()` method is

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.Current.Shutdown()`